# Bottom rounded corners broken in Bootstrap after custom css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the last version 3.3.0, but since 3.2.0 I have this issue. The inferior round corners do not connect.

With 3.2.0:

[image]

With  3.1.1:

[image]

I just found if I add the following line:

`background-color: #ffffff !important;`

and changing the:

`padding: 15px;`

to

`padding: 0px;`

to the class:

`.panel-body`

it breaks the inferior round corners.

How can I force the panel-body to have a white background and 0px padding?

http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/730sjq8n/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following style:

```
.panel-body {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

The issue was that while you gave the container a border and a border-radius, you had the content within the container a background of white with no border-radius. Therefore, you had a round box with a square block inside it, thus cutting off the border slightly.

Add a border radius to the content allowed the content to fit inside your container.

Alternatively, you can remove the background color:

```
.panel-body { background-color: transparent;
}
```

That would also be a fix.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: @chdltest, I have created another question with the full example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819556/panel-inside-panel-in-bootstrap-not-creating-rounded-corners thanks again.